# javascript image onError in case of non 200 response

Tags: javascript, handler, onload, http-status-code-302, onerror

I have to count image loading time. onLoadHandler is responsible for it.

```
<img onError="onErrorHandler(this);" onLoad="onLoadHandler(this);" alt="" border='0' width='1' height='1'   src='http://exmaple.com/02.jpg'/>
```

It is works fine if image is normal file with 200 server response.

But partners provide chain of 302 redirects, and onError fires on first redirect.
So i never get real loading image time.

Is there some workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question, although I don't  think there is going to be a workaround. `onload` and `onerror` support for images is traditionally very shaky in browsers

Comment: is there official documentation about onError dependency on server response code?

Comment: @Lev AFAIK, `onerror` is not an official event for images - I know of no good source that defines or explains what it is supposed to do exactly.

Comment: every tutorial says there is one
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: @Lev generally, in my experience, w3schools is not a good source on deep issues like this one... Anyway, the event is *supported* in browsers but it's not officially defined in a standard. Therefore, what happens in case of 302 redirects and such might vary from browser to browser.

Comment: Typically, the browser is quite strict when it comes to loading resources from another domain or even subdomain. Even more strict when doing redirects across domains... Are you doing cross domain redirects?

Comment: Even though it's firing onError, does it eventually fire an onLoad anyway? (I'm guessing no, from the context, but thought I'd ask to clarify)

Comment: id does fire onLoad if it has 200 response eventually with valid image.

Comment: Not sure, but you could try to check the HTTPStatus code in the onError handler and return false.

Comment: turned out that onLoad never fires if server send non image header.
i tested it only in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Is the size of the image that you're redirected to the same size as the image you requested? If not, you can use this to detect an error.